# Date formatting in Google Scripts/Mail - Method not found Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script to send mails from a spreadsheet and like to format the date. I'm using `Utilities.formatDate` and this works but gives me also an error: "Method formatDate(string,string,string) not found"

```
var message = "<p><b>Ressort: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Textart: </b>" + CurrentRow[7] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Domain: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Thema: </b>" + CurrentRow[8] + "</p>" + "<p><b>Deadline: </b>" + Utilities.formatDate(CurrentRow[2], "GMT+2" , "dd.MM.yyyy") + "</p>";
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You need `Utilities.formatDate(Date, String, String)`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

`CurrentRow[2]` is coming up as type `String`, instead of `Date`.

If `CurrentRow[2]` is of [a format that the Date object can parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), then try wrapping it in `new Date(CurrentRow[2])`.